# present continuous for a general statement: is it possible?

Tags: continuous

> In fact i live in France but Scott (who lives in Australia) is such a nice guy that he is ok to let me use his address, so each record I buy in Australia is delivered to him, where they **are waiting** to be sent with all  the records  already  on hold.

As it is a general statement would it be possible to use the present simple?

> In fact i live in France but Scott (who lives in Australia) is such a nice guy that he is ok to let me use his address, so each record I buy in Australia is delivered to him, where they **wait**  to be sent with all  the records  already  on hold.

I think the continuous is better because the wait has a duration

Would it be possible write this?

> In fact i live in France but Scott (who lives in Australia) is such a nice guy that he is ok to let me use his address, so each record I bought in Australia is delivered to him,  ***waiting*** to be sent with all  the records  already  on hold.

Comment: oú ils attendent in French would be: they're waiting in English. [He is OK with *letting me use his address*]/ THEY, the records?? Frankly, I don't think wait is good here. If he is receiving and holding records for you, the records would not be said to be waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples are possible but neither is clear or concise. It's not clear who is buying the records.

Is this what you mean?

**I live in France but my friend Scott in Australia allows me to use his address 
for the records I buy there, where they wait to be parcelled up (or packaged) and sent on to me.**